# Using Proguard on App Engine code

Tags: java, google-app-engine, proguard

I'm using Proguard in my Android app and it optimize the app a lot by removing and merging classes based on what I use. Is the same possible for the code that I run on Google App Engine? I always hear that the startup time of an App Engine instance is related to the number and sizes of the jar file it has to scan.

So, my questions is, can I use Proguard on App Engine and how can it be integrated? Had anyone done this before? Or doesn't it had any positive impact on the warm up requests or performance?

Answer (score 0):

This should be possible with the ProGuard maven plugin.

See also the related issue [here](https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=4025) where some people posted links to their setup to run process during their war generation.

Comment: To bad I'm using Gradle for building and deploying my application to App Engine. But thanks for you answer anyway. Will check it out.

Comment: Which makes it probably even easier, see documentation how to include a custom ProGuard task into your gradle build: http://proguard.sourceforge.net/manual/gradle.html